# Xcode and Command Line Tools aren't working properly?

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-m1

I've had no end of issues with trying to get Xcode Simulators to work for React Native.

Running commands to start the iOS simulator as part of RN gets me:

```
Unable to run simctl:
Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 72
CommandError: xcrun is not configured correctly. Ensure `sudo xcode-select --reset` works before running this command again.
```

Running `sudo xcode-select --reset` runs without error, but then when I run `yarn ios` again it just spits out the same error.

I'm using Xcode 14.3.1 on an M1 Pro Mac on Ventura 13.5, and it's worth noting that I've never been able to get iOS simulators to work on this laptop yet.

I've done the "Settings -> Locations -> Make sure Command Line Tools is selected from the dropdown"  fix that seems to work for most
[image: showing I've done the selection]

I've tried downloading Xcode/Command Line Tools from developer.apple.com / command line / the mac app store in many combinations and nothing has worked

Comment: The screenshot you gave you do "in a GUI way" the `xcode-select selectXCodeVersion`, does `xcode-select -p` gives you the correct one too? Also, after `--reset`, you might need to re select one.